# display many fields in a collection form symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I have added a collection to my form.

```
->add('numbers', 'collection', array('type'         => new NumberType(),
                                              'allow_add'    => true,
                                              'allow_delete' => true))
```

The numberType has two fields : From and To. 
I want to display both of them in the form.
How to do that?

Comment: would you mind describing what you want to achieve?
A form with one subform? A form with multiple subforms?
A form with multiple (dynamic amount) subforms?

Comment: I want to dispaly a form with multiple subforms @DerStoffel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't get your problem, but rendering a form with its collection Fields is as simple as what's described [on the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/forms/types/collection.html)

```
->add('numbers', 'collection', array(
    'type' => new NumberType(),
    // ...
    ));
```

**Simple rendering,**

```
   {{ form_row(yourForm.numbers) }}
```

**Customized rendering,**

```
<ul>
{% for number in yourForm.numbers %}
    <li>
        {{ form_errors(number) }}
        {# form_label(number) #} {# If you want to render a label for earch given number #}
        {{ form_widget(number) }}
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Actually my problem is that my numberType is as follows  $builder
            ->add('From')
            ->add('To') and I want to display both of fields 'From' and 'To'

Comment: form_widget(number) displays both fields. And you can also call form_row() or form_widget() on "number.From" and "number.To"

Comment: I can not get anything displayed even with {{ form_row(yourForm.numbers) }}

Comment: You main entity should be related to numbers and well bound to you form so that you can get numbers on your form.
Also, take a look at this detailed example on [How to Embed a Collection of Forms](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/form/form_collections.html).

Comment: what if I have a one to many relation with the entity I am adding to it the NumberType?

Comment: when I use the enity everything is ok ->add('numbers', 'entity', array(
              'class'    => '***Bundle:Number',
     'property'=> 'From', 
              'multiple' => false)) What might be the problem?@Ahmed Siouani

Comment: You've to debug until you get what's going wrong, the example I gave you is a full working implementation of a oneToMany relation using collection Field, you've to adapt this implementation to your case.